# Asset Pipeline issues deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I'm running a Rails 5 app, Ruby 2.4 specified in my Gemfile. I've read through the Heroku assets pipeline article, and gone through the steps as I think I should.

In config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.compile = true
```

In /config/assets, I have these lines:

```
Rails.application.config.serve_static_assets = true
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( customers.js )
```

customers.js is the only file I specifically include at the top of a page, and Rails requires me to precompile it..

Just before deploying to Heroku using git, I run this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

If you go to https://crateu.herokuapp.com, you'll see the stylesheet isn't handling the nav properly (I'm using the Materialize gem). What's confusing to me, is that the javascript is working for the dropdown items. And the styles that handle the nav are in application.sass, and the file is included - it's just not working.

If you go to an invalid URL, such as https://crateu.herokuapp.com/badurl, everything looks the way it should.

I have //= require_tree . in application.js, and when I view the source locally, I see all the files in the pipeline, and everything renders properly. I copied and pasted that source into 404.html in /public, which is why that page renders properly. When I view source on the herokuapp, none of those resources are included in the header. I'm sure it's something simple, a setting somewhere that I'm missing. Maybe I need to include everything in this line, not just customers.js?

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( customers.js )
```

I've tried everything I can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you included it [correctly](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass#usage)? Do you have `uglifier` in your `Gemfile` in the assets group?

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your comment. No I do not have uglifier in my Gemfile in the assets group. What would that look like? Sorry, this is the first I've heard of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put the response here because the comment section doesn't allow to me to put multiline code, you've to add to you Gemfile:

```
 group :assets do
    gem 'uglifier'
 end
```

Comment: Ah, okay, got it - sorry, I have it included in my Gemfile regardless of the group - gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'. So it should be included, regardless of the group.

Comment: Can you see the `customers.js` code in https://crateu.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b5ada9bf8b626596facfd4f92db04275f58a72a9cd6ac6ec567aef60a491da32.js?

Comment: Sorry, it is the css or the js?

Comment: Yes, if I go to the one page/view where it's included, I can see it. But it doesn't make a difference - the issue is somehow related to the materlialize css.

Comment: I can't see a difference between the index and the 404 page, also I see the materialize css in the [application.css](https://crateu.herokuapp.com/assets/application-a7de24b7c2454bd55b7b1755814658b9344a71f6a84feacc179424da98d5bb16.css). You should remove `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

Comment: Yeah, the 404 page was working but after making some more changes, the nav on that page stopped working, too. I voted for your answer but my reputation isn't high enough for it to be displayed in the total score. Mentioning application.css made me dig deeper into the assets folder and it seems I had some .sass files and some scss. When I ensured they were all .sass, that fixed the problem. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed the problem, at least you can mark the answer correct, but in this case isn't correct.